# Window function sum, multiplied by condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, operators, spark-window-function

I am reviewing a code and would love to have a bit more clarity.

Here is my PySpark Dataframe:

| YEAR_A | YEAR_B | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 2001 | 5 |
| 2000 | 2000 | 4 |
| 2000 | 2001 | 3 |

I initiate a window function:

```py
window = Window.partitionBy('YEAR_A')
```

Then I would love some help to understand the following part, especially after the `over(window)`.

```py
df = (df.withColumn("newcolumn", F.sum("AMOUNT").over(window) *(F.col("YEAR_B") == F.col("YEAR_A")).cast("integer")))
```

Is it supposed to create a "newcolumn" to my dataframe with the sum of "AMOUNT" of the current YEAR_A and write it only if "YEAR_A" is equal to "YEAR_B" (otherwise write nan)? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`(F.col("YEAR_B") == F.col("YEAR_A"))` compares both columns. If the values in the row are equal, you get `True`, if they are not equal, you get `False`.

`.cast("integer")` makes the integer out of the previous result. `True` becomes `1`, `False` becomes `0`.

`F.sum("AMOUNT").over(window) *` - you multiply the result of the window function with the result of above. When you multiply by `1`, you get the value of the window function. When you multiply by `0`, you get `0`.

There's nothing written about `nan`. Spark does not return `nan` generally.